# Does increasing headlight wattage affects motorcycle mileage

Tags: motorcycle, headlight

I ride **Honda CD-100 SS**, a 100cc motorcycle.

Does increasing the wattage of the headlight bulb affect the mileage(fuel efficiency) of the motorcycle? If it does please explain how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not increasing the load on the engine then mileage(fuel-efficiency) remains unaffected.

- Primary source of electrical energy on **Honda CD100SS** is the **magneto**, an alternator that cuts magnetic flux from permanent magnets.
- This alternator generates AC following the principle of [Electromagnetic Induction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_induction)
- A battery is used as the source of DC. Battery gets charging current from AC generated from magneto after going through Rectifier-Regulator circuit.
- AC so generated is fed through a Rectifier/Regulator, which performs AC-to-DC conversion, clipping higher voltages etc.
- In most Indian motorcycles headlight is powered by AC coming out of regulator.

Coming to your question, when you replace say a **35W(12v)** bulb with **50W(12v)** then new bulb will not glow to its full capacity.

However, if you rewind the stator-coil to produce more current then technically more load is on the engine. This load from **stator(magneto)** will always be there whenever engine is on.

Answer (score 5):

Not by any amount you can measure, no. The power consumed by the bulbs are such a small fraction of the total that you would not notice it, unless you are adding multiple spotlights or going all retro-mod, maybe, like this [pic from the Telegraph](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/2620126/Classic-Vespa-falls-foul-of-EU-emissions-rules.html):

[image]